# how to declare color for Label

Tags: objective-c

I have done simple application its just like when a tab  a button it will  show a messsage like "How do u do"
Now I want to  keep a color to the TEXt.
How do I it? I have written like below

```
#import "tr1ViewController.h"

@implementation tr1ViewController

- (IBAction)butt
{
  label.text = @"HI How do u do" ;
  label.UIColor=ColorWithName:"@red";
}
```

Please let me know the Declaration

Answer (score 3):

```
label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
```